# Dual booting Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

Yet another question on this topic.  Sorry.

I've bought a new HP Pavilion 15-p239sa with Windows 8.1 installed, and I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04.  The problem is that after installation of Ubuntu, it still just boots to Windows without displaying the GRUB menu for me to pick Ubuntu.  Here is the sequence of events:

1. Download Ubuntu 14.04 from the Ubuntu web site and burn to DVD
2. Install Ubuntu as directed and reboot: laptop boots to Windows only
3. Install and run boot-repair from live disk as instructed.  Boot-repair says to disable secure boot
4. Disable secure boot and reboot.  No change.
5. Install and run boot-repair again from live disk.  No errors reported.
6. Re-boot.  Still can only access Windows.
7. Ran bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi. Ran OK and reported no errors.
8. Re-boot.  Still can only boot Windows.  GRUB menu still not showing.

The report from boot-repair is at: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10826849/

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help.

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how the issue was resolved in my case, with the help of the volunteers at Boot-Repair:

1. Do a normal install of Ubuntu alongside Windows following the well-known instructions (turn off secure boot, turn off fast boot etc etc). In other words do the stuff I'd done before posting this question.
2. If Ubuntu is inaccessible, run Boot Repair from a live disc and try again. If Ubuntu is still inaccessible, try the following.
3. Boot on your Ubuntu live-disc and choose "Try Ubuntu". Then open a terminal when you're in Ubuntu and type the following commands:
   `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`
   `sudo mv /mnt/EFI/HP /mnt/EFI/HPbkp`
   `sudo mv /mnt/EFI/Microsoft /mnt/EFI/Microsoftbkp`

For me, this made the machine boot into Ubuntu instead of Windows, but still did not show the GRUB menu. This being the case, I then had to do the following

4. Open a terminal in Ubuntu and type: `gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/25_custom`
5. Edit the text 25_custom text file, replacing: `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` with 
   `/EFI/Microsoftbkp/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`
6. Reboot and select `Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi` from the GRUB menu (which now did appear), to get into Windows. Select `Ubuntu` to get into Ubuntu, obviously.

Obviously the names of partitions (e.g. sda2) and text files (e.g. 25_custom) may well be unique to a particular installation. There are also some things here that are clearly specific to HP, like `/mnt/EFI/HP`.

I hope this gives some pointers to other people struggling with this and kudos to the Boot-Repair team.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a step by step on how I did it:
 1. Install Windows 8.1
 2. disable secureboot in bios (or in some cases allow it to run other Os's)
 3. turn off fast boot
 4. install ubuntu alongside windows.

Comment: Can you tell me how to install ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1 which was pre built in my Sony Vaio laptop?

Comment: Thanks, but I already did all that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Boot your Ubuntu installation disc, but select the "try before installing" option.
2. Open a Terminal window.
3. Verify that the `/sys/firmware/efi` directory is present. If not, reboot in EFI mode. (You were in EFI mode when you installed.)
4. Type `sudo efibootmgr -o 2,2002,1,3001`. This command changes the boot order so that GRUB is first. (See lines 954-963 in your Boot Repair output.) Note that you can change the order and the included options as you see fit; the critical point is that `2` be first in the list, since that's your GRUB. (This number varies from system to system; for somebody else it may be some other value.)
5. Reboot.

If that doesn't fix it, my recommendation is to return the computer to the store for a refund, buy another brand, and write a letter to HP explaining the problem and telling them that you returned the computer because of it. Your EFI *should not* have the problem that you describe, and if it doesn't work correctly after the fix I've described, it means that the firmware is badly defective, like a TV with half the image missing or a stereo that can play nothing but polka music. Unfortunately, manufacturers have been putting out junky EFIs for years, and they'll continue to do so unless customers stop being sheep and communicate their displeasure with the junky EFIs. Returning a system is the only effective means of communication we have, since manufacturers give other forms of communication scant attention.

If you're willing to accept a defective firmware, you can rename your boot files to trick the computer into launching GRUB rather than the Windows boot loader. There's an option to do this on the Boot Repair Advanced menu; or you can do it manually, as described [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#naming) with respect to rEFInd, although you'll need to tweak the filenames for use with GRUB. You'll also need to generate a new GRUB menu (via `sudo update-grub`) after a manual update.

Comment: I suspect this would have solved the problem. Unfortunately I didn't see your response until after I'd solved the matter as described below: but I think I've effectively done what you suggest in your last paragraph.

Comment: BTW, whilst I sympathise greatly with what you say about returning the machine, I'm afraid I would get nowhere with this -- under UK law at least.  The shop would argue I bought a Windows machine and it works as advertised and is not defective if used as recommended.  I know it's more complex than that, but in the space available here I think you'll get my drift. W10 will be worse, from what I hear.

Answer (score 0):

Open your boot settings. And go to **system configuration** section. Then select OS boot manager. Each firmware has its own paths to reach there , in some cases you can see it under **boot options**. Somehow reach **OS BOOT MANAGER** option as per your firmware.  Then hit enter over  **OS BOOT MANAGER** you will see two options windows and ubuntu's boot file. Use f5 of f6 as per your firmware to move it upwards or downwards(it will be listed there) . Ubuntu's boot file must be given priority.then save and exit. 
Now your system will be working fine.
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately some badly implemented UEFIs require additional steps for some machines and either way, nice attempt, but it's NOT possible to guve one generic answer where so many variants (also in terminology) exist today. Users should be directed first and foremost to their user's manuals and other model specific documentation.